# Wifi not showing in my PC 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless, atheros

Wifi networks are not listing in my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop. I have seen lots of similar post here, but no one helps.

This is the error I get in my terminal:

```
wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

Output of   `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill` list is:-

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] 
 (rev 30)
  Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:0806]
  Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
  Kernel modules: ath10k_pci, wl
  0: hci0: Bluetooth
  Soft blocked: yes
  Hard blocked: no
  1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no
```

[Software and updates of my laptop as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMeKr.png)

Output of `dmesg | grep ath` as follows:

```
[   21.590152] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi interrupts 1 
irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   22.023398] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for 
ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[   22.023427] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for 
ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[   22.023433] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 
'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
 [   22.023448] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for 
ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-4.bin failed with error -2
[   22.023452] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 
'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-4.bin': -2
 [   22.023466] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for 
ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-3.bin failed with error -2
 [   22.023470] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 
'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-3.bin': -2
[   22.023481] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for 
 ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-2.bin failed with error -2
 [   22.023484] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 
 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-2.bin': -2
 [   22.023491] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for 
 ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware.bin failed with error -2
 [   22.023493] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware (-2)
 [   22.023496] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware 
 files 
 (-2)
 [   22.023498] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not probe fw (-2)
```

Output of apt-cache policy linux-firmware as follows:

```
linux-firmware:
Installed: 1.157
Candidate: 1.157
Version table:
*** 1.157 500
    500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
    500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64304/discussion-on-question-by-youv-wifi-not-showing-in-my-pc-16-04).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your `linux-firmware`. It looks like software sources for updates are not enabled.

Go to System Settings -> Software & Updates and enable all sources.

Connect by wire to the internet, the system will suggest to update sources, then run

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

The system will get updates, and the Wi-Fi should work after a reboot.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for the reply .Let me check.